# Кража куки с phpsessid

Tags: php, безопасность

На сайте
session_start(3600);
После этого у пользователя на ПК появляется кука с идентификатором сессии.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю что украв после этого куку с компьютера пользователя можно без проблем зайти на сайт под его логином и работать там но сделать это только в течение часа (3600 сек)
2. Со стороны сайта этому противостоять довольно сложно. Если только ip в сессию записывать и сравнивать?

Comment: дак вы возьмите в другом браузере да пропишите куку при запросе

Comment: @teran как это сделать?

Comment: в фаирфоксе ф12, сеть. обновляете страницу. находите основной запрос к странице. Справа параметры запроса, жмете "Изменить и снова отправить", редактируете параметры/куки.

Comment: 3600 - некорректный параметр для session_start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Совершенно правильно.
2. Запись IP тоже не поможет на 100%. Обычно перехват если и делается, то в момент работы сессии. А IP запросто можно подменить в запросе.
   Простого решения тут нет. Один и тот же легальный пользователь может в одном и том же браузере на отдном и том же компьютере открыть две и более сессий.И это должно быть совсем легально. А нелегальный пользователь может заменитьпроцесс обмена одной или более сессий, вклинившись в середину этой цепочки обмена.